# Suppose $P$ is a non singular $m\times m$ matrix and $A$ be any $m\times n$ matrix,then how to interpret that $A$ and $PA$ have same row space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have recently encountered a theorem in linear algebra which states that if $P$ is an $m\times m$ matrix and $A$ is $m\times n$,then $A$ and $PA$ share the same row space.I have understood the proof but I want to make it intuitively clear.Can I visualize it in some way in terms of linear transformations?
                                                           One way to interpret is that $P$ can be thought as a series of elementary row transforamtions $E_1E_2...E_k$ and $PA$ is the output of that that is I am just adding,multiplying by scalar and manipulating the same row vectors,so row space should remain same.
But I am not happy with that interpretation.
                     I tried to put it another way that $P$ is an isomorphism on $\mathbb R^m$.Now I am multiplying $A$ by $P$ from left.Can I see how this $P$ acts on the individual row vectors of $A$?

Comment: By "having the same row space" you mean that the row spaces have the same dimension? Or do you mean *the same*?

Comment: of course same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a matrix $B$, let us denote by $Im(B)$ the image of it as a linear map, by $row(B)$ its row space, and by $col(B)$ its column space.

Now, since the row space of a matrix is just its transpose column space, and since the image of a matrix [as a linear map] equals the span of its columns, we have

$row(PA) = col((PA)^T) = col(A^T P^T) = Im(A^T P^T)$.

Now, $det(P^T) = det(P) \neq 0$, so we have that $P^T$ is also invertible.

what can you say about $Im(CD)$ and $Im(C)$ where C,D are matrices, and D is invertible?

Answer (score 1):

You're right that since $P$ is an invertible $m\times m$ matrix, it can be interpreted as an isomorphism $P: \Bbb{R}^m \to \Bbb{R}^m$ (technically, it is abuse of notation to use the same letter $P$ for the matrix and also the associated linear transformation, but I hope this doesn't confuse you too much).

Next, you should note that given any $m\times n$ matrix $B$, its row space is by definition the linear span of its rows:
\begin{align}
\text{row}(B) &= \text{span of rows of $B$}
\end{align}
Another equivalent way of saying this is to say that the row space of a matrix is the image when multiplying the matrix on the left by a row-vector:
\begin{align}
\text{row}(B) = \left\{x\cdot B \big| \, \text{ $x \in \Bbb{R}^m$ is a row vector} \right\}
\end{align}
In general, if $S$ is any subset of $\Bbb{R}^m$, then it is convenient to use the notation
\begin{align}
[S] B = \left\{ x\cdot B \big| \,  \text{ $x \in S$ is a row vector} \right \}
\end{align}

With this notation, we can write $\text{row}(B) = [\Bbb{R}^m] B$. Now, let's apply this to your particular example. To do so, we apply the above discussion to the matrix $PA$:
\begin{align}
\text{row}(PA) &= [\Bbb{R}^m]\cdot (PA) \\
&= \left[ [\Bbb{R}^m] P \right] \cdot A \\
&= \left[\text{row}(P)\right] A \\
&= \left[ \Bbb{R}^m \right]A \tag{$*$} \\
&= \text{row}(A)
\end{align}

You should be able to verify each of the equal signs by unwinding the definitions I presented above. Note that in $(*)$, I used the fact that for an invertible matrix $P$ (i.e an isomorphism) its row space is equal to the entire $\Bbb{R}^m$ (try to prove this by yourself).

Comment: Best answer by @peek-a-boo.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ and $PA$ have the same kernel since $P$ is injective. The row space of a matrix is the set of vectors in the domain space which are orthogonal to (all vectors in) the kernel (i.e. the orthogonal complement of the null space of the matrix). So $A$ and $PA$ have the same row space since they have the same kernel.

Comment: I still do not know inner product and orthogonal vectors,I am new student in BSc maths.